# `unbuffer` or `stdbuf` for removing stdout buffering?

Tags: utilities, io, stdout, buffer

Is there a difference between unbuffer(1) and stdbuf(1)? From what I gather, unbuffer makes more than the "best effort" of calling the libc function set(X)buf at the beginning, and then letting things be?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

They work in completely different ways.

The program unbuffer uses expect to run the named command. Because expect creates a pseudo-tty to attach to the stdout of the child process, the child might be fooled into thinking that it should use line-buffering instead of block-buffering. Some programs will change their behaviour when isatty(stdout) is true, others won't and it is very hard to know which will and which won't.

The program stdbuf attempts to put libstdbuf in front of libc for dynamically loaded binaries. Where libstdbuf redefines the default buffering strategy of the libc stdio calls.

I found this out by

```
 apt-get source expect coreutils
```

and reading the relevant source for each program.

Comment: Some worrying stuff (from manpage): `unbuffer -p` may appear to work incorrectly if a process feeding input to unbuffer exits.  Consider: `process1 | unbuffer -p process2 | process3` If  process1  exits,  process2  may  not  yet  have finished.  It is impossible for unbuffer to know long to wait

Comment: It seems stdbuf can also control the stdin buffering of programs that use C streams, which seems important. Perhaps this should be included in the answer for the benefit of future readers.

Answer (score 1):

### TL;DR

The [older, accepted answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/97327/17673) is still correct. The main difference in my own experience is that *unbuffer* is simpler to use and provides only one switch (`-p`) for use in pipelines to buffer standard input, which *unbuf* will not do.

While specific use cases may vary, I'd offer the follow general advice:

1. Use *unbuffered* if you need to buffer standard input and understand the limitations of buffering standard input, i.e. hanging if the pipeline exits early or early termination on EOF.
2. Use *stdbuf* when you need separate control over the buffering for input, output, and error I/O streams, and if you don't need to buffer standard input.

### Stdbuf from Coreutils

The *[stdbuf](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/stdbuf-invocation.html)* utility, which is part of GNU [coreutils](/questions/tagged/coreutils), offers separate flags for input, output, and error streams. Notably, the man page makes the following key points:

1. Commands like tee that adjust buffers themselves will be unaffected.
2. Filters that don't use I/O streams aren't affected.
3. Line buffering is invalid with standard input.

So, in general, *stdbuf* gives you more control than *unbuffer*, but there are a number of caveats. `man 1 stdbuf` (or `man 1 gstdbuf` on some systems) says:

> NOTE: If COMMAND adjusts the buffering of its standard streams ('tee' does for example) then that will override corresponding changes by 'stdbuf'. Also some filters (like 'dd' and 'cat' etc.) don't use streams for I/O, and are thus unaffected by 'stdbuf' settings...
>
> BUGS 
> On GLIBC platforms, specifying a buffer size, i.e., using fully buffered mode will result in undefined operation.

### Unbuffered from Expect

The *[unbuffered](https://core.tcl-lang.org/expect/example/unbuffer.man.html)* command, which is one of the standard [expect](/questions/tagged/expect) command line example tools, offers fewer knobs to twiddle. This may or may not be a benefit for you. Personally, I prefer simplicity unless I *need* the additional knobs. On the other hand, while *stdbuf* won't work with standard input, *unbuffered* can when using the `-p` option.

> Normally, unbuffer does not read from stdin.  This simplifies use of unbuffer in some situations. To use unbuffer in a pipeline, use the -p flag.

However, this behavior comes with a caveat and some further explanation about why if you read `man 1 unbuffered`:

> unbuffer -p may appear to work incorrectly if a process feeding input to unbuffer exits.  Consider:
>
> process1 | unbuffer -p process2 | process3
>
> If process1 exits, process2 may not yet have finished. It is impossible for unbuffer to know long to wait for process2 and process2 may not ever finish, for example, if it is a filter. For expediency, unbuffer simply exits when it encounters an EOF from either its input or process2.

In such cases, *unbuffered* recommends hand-tuning the pipeline, using Expect directly, or various other workarounds instead.

Comment: See also: [Why does unbuffer -p mangle its input?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/760143)