# stderr gets flushed before stdout, when using file logger

Tags: logs, python, nohup, stderr

My python code:

```
import sys
print "i am a daemon"
print "i will be run using nohup"
sys.stderr.write("i am an error message inside nohup process\n")
```

When i run the code as `python a.py`, it shows,

```
i am a daemon
i will be run using nohup
i am an error message inside nohup process
```

When i run the code as `nohup python a.py > a.log 2>&1 < /dev/null &` , a.log shows,

```
i am an error message inside nohup process
i am a daemon
i will be run using nohup
```

Why does stderr logs get flushed/written before stdout logs when using `nohup`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don't think it's got anything to do with `nohup`. You get the same behavior when you do `python a.py > a.log 2>&1`.

Python is most likely using C file stdio underneath. With that, `stdout`, when in a terminal, will be line-buffered, and buffered when `stdout` is a file. `stderr` is always unbuffered.

Redirecting `stdout` to a file will switch `stdout`'s buffering from line-buffered to buffered and cause the `print`ed string to be stuck in the buffer, which only gets flushed when your program (the stream) closes. The `stderr` stream makes it to the file faster because it's unbuffered.

You can use `stdbuf` to tweak standard buffering, forcing the lines to print in the correct order:

```
stdbuf -o0 python a.py  >a.log 2>&1
```

Answer (score 2):

This is normal behavior for output streams in most languages: they are [buffered](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_buffer), i.e. `write` actually writes to a buffer in memory and this buffer is written out to the stream in batches. Stdout is line buffered when writing to a terminal (i.e. an actual write takes place every time a newline is printed) but fully buffered (the data is written to memory until the memory buffer gets full) when writing to a regular file or a pipe. Stderr is either unbuffered or line buffered.

In Python, you can choose the type of buffering when opening a file, but not for the standard streams. If you want all streams to be unbuffered, you can set the [`PYTHONUNBUFFERED`](http://docs.python.org/2/using/cmdline.html#envvar-PYTHONUNBUFFERED) environment variable to force the standard streams to be unbuffered. Alternatively, you can [run the program under `stdbuf` or `unbuffer`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/97294/unbuffer-or-stdbuf-for-removing-stdout-buffering).

But if your program doesn't emit output in an appropriate order when stdout is redirected, that's a defect in the program, which you should fix. In particular, if you're going to emit an error message that concerns output written to stdout, you should flush stdout first:

```
print some_data
if errro_condition():
    file.stdout.flush()
    sys.stderr.write('Bad stuff happened\n')
```