# Bash script - run application and show live output

Tags: bash, output, application

I've got a bash script that sets up some environment parameters and then runs a c++ application.

The c++ application outputs information showing it's current state as it runs.

Currently, I only see the results of this once it's finished running. (approx 1 min) Is there anyway to have the bash script show the live output from the application ?

This is what I have so far:

```
OUTPUT="$(sudo ./test_app -release)"    
echo $OUTPUT
```

I get the following once the application has completed.:

```
release acknowledgereleasingstage1stage2released
```

If I ran the application direct from the command line, I'd get this as new line as each process completed, not all in one when the application completed.

```
release acknowledge
releasing
stage1
stage2
released
```

Any ideas how to do this ? I'd like to call the app from the bash script to save the users having to run multiple commands.

Thanks.

Comment: Replace `OUTPUT="$(sudo ./test_app -release)"` with `sudo ./test_app -release` in your script?

Comment: Thanks that seems to work... not sure why I didn't think of doing that !

Comment: Alternatively, if you want to store the output for rebroadcast later (or processing):  `SCRATCH=$(mktemp); ./test_app -release > $SCRATCH 2>&1; [other stuff]; cat $SCRATCH; rm $SCRATCH`

Answer (score 3):

If you want to show the output and don't need to save it, just run the command:

```
sudo ./test_app -release
```

If you want to both save the output and display it, call [`tee`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/tee.1.html) to duplicate the output.

```
OUTPUT=$(sudo ./test_app -release | tee /dev/stderr)
```

When you redirect the output, the application may [buffer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_buffer) its output in large chunks instead of line by line. Line by line is the default only when the output is a terminal, not when it's a pipe or a regular file. If this is the case with your application, [call `unbuffer` or `stdbuff`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/25372/turn-off-buffering-in-pipe). Due to [the way they work](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/97294/unbuffer-or-stdbuf-for-removing-stdout-buffering), `stdbuf` needs to be invoked by sudo, whereas `buffer` can run as you.

```
OUTPUT=$(sudo stdbuf ./test_app -release | tee /dev/stderr)
OUTPUT=$(unbuffer sudo ./test_app -release | tee /dev/stderr)
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you don't need to store the output for any specific reason, you can simply replace,

```
OUTPUT="$(sudo ./test_app -release)"    
echo $OUTPUT
```

with

```
sudo ./test_app -release
```

There's no special difference in shell scripts between built in commands and non-built in commands (at the basic level).  They all just execute and output stuff.